# Название файла для file_put_content()

Tags: php

Мне нужно сделать следующее:

```
file_put_contents('data/кошка.txt', 'string');
```

на что  выходит ошибка:

```
Warning: file_put_contents(data/кошка.txt): failed to open stream: Illegal byte sequence
```

Название файла обязательно должно быть русским. Подскажите, пожалуйста, как можно это сделать?

P.S.: если написать

```
file_put_contents('data/cat.txt', 'string');
```

то все ок.

Comment: Права на запись дайте

Comment: Очень странно, у меня все работает https://imgur.com/a/pMjGHMR

Comment: Если у вас Linux попробуйте `chmod -R 777 .`

Comment: у меня Mac OS X

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Решила проблему - работаю в PHPStorm, кодировка проекта стояла windows-1251, поменяла на utf-8 и всё заработало.

Answer (score 0):

Вы пытаетесь записать файл в несуществующую папку. Сделайте сперва проверку на существование директории, и в случае отсутствия создайте её, а после - записывайте в неё файл `кошка.txt`:

```
$dir = 'data';
is_dir($dir) ?: mkdir($dir);
file_put_contents("$dir/кошка.txt", 'string');
```

Comment: нет, папка data существует. Я пробовала написать "cat" вместо "кошка", и тогда все норм, так что дело в русских буквах

Comment: @КатяБоева у меня записался файл с русским названием, но только после создания папки. А покуда папки не было, скрипт возвращал такую же ошибку.

Comment: ну у меня папка существует. Да даже и без папки если попробовать, просто "кошка.txt", всё равно выходит точно такая же ошибка